# Determine whether the following series is convergent or divergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I am asked to determine whether or not the following series converges or diverges:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty C_n$ where $C_1 = 2$ and $C_{n+1} = \sqrt{C_n+1}$

Now my first thought was to determine if {$C_n$} diverges else this will tell me that the series diverges. But based on my calculations the sequence seems to converge. So I can't conclude anything there. My next bet was to try to determine if the limit of C$_n$ is 0 as n tends to infinity. However, I got stuck there. I also tried using the ratio test but again, I got stuck. Can anyone give me a hint as to what might be a good approach?

Comment: Since $C_n>0$ does it not follow that $C_{n+1}= \sqrt{C_{n}+1}>1$? This seems to imply $\lim_{n \to \infty} C_n > 1 >0$.

Comment: Intuitively yes, however I was trying to figure out how I could formally show that? However, I see what you did, I'm just not sure if thats worth 6 marks for the question.

Comment: Umm...isn't that formal enough? If you want to invole $\epsilon-N$ definition, you could just say that if $\lim_{n \to \infty}C_n = 0$ then there must be such $N$ that $|C_{n}|<1$ for all $n>N$ ($\epsilon = 1$). Clearly such $N$ does not exist so $\lim_{n \to \infty} C_{n} \neq 0$.

Comment: @DonnaPaul What S.C.B. is proposing is as formal as you may need. If $\;c_n\ge 1\;$ then it can't possibly be, directly by definition, that $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} c_n=0\;$ (just take $\;\epsilon=\frac12\;$ in that definition, say), so the series cannot possibly converge.

Comment: Okay, I understand. I was just concerned at the marks allocated to the question. Thank you all.

Comment: you can actually $\textit{phi}$nd the limit of this sequence. it is not zero, so the series can’t  converge, but the sequence has a nice limit.